# jQuery function not called when runat = "server" is used in an image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I have an html image tag in an aspx page. The image when clicked performs certain jQuery functions. Recently I added the  attribute to the image because I wanted to change the source of the image based on certain validation. But the problem is I am not understanding why the jQuery functions are not called when I click the image, when it used to work perfectly fine when there was no  attribute. I have looked at every possible solutions on the web and tried it as well but none did work.

Please find the below codes and let me know what I can do to make this work.

**ASPX page: Jquery functions and the image tag code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= ResolveUrl("~/Common/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1")%>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= ResolveUrl("~/Common/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min")%>"></script>
```

`$(document).ready(function () {
//doing something`

`$("#imgseats").click(function () {
// doing something
});`
`});`

`</script>`

```
<ul id="list">
        <li id="listSeats" runat="server">
            <img id="imgseats" class="HeaderGradient" src="../../Common/Images/seatsPCPI.jpg" alt="Seats" runat="server" />

            //some code here
            </li>
 </ul>
```

**Code behind aspx.cs**

```
if(condition)
{
    imgseats.Attributes["src"] = "../../Common/Images/seatsPCPI_MandatoryPI.jpg";
}
```

Please help me with resolving this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's because the `runat="server"` attribute effectively changes the element in to a server side control. As such any interaction with it will cause a postback, and the page is then reloaded. This means that any JS you have attached to the element is not executed, or is executed but then undone by the page reload.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I understand. But please tell me how can I solve my problem of changing the image source without compromising the execution of the JS?

Comment: Either make the change to the `src` in the server side, or remove the `runat` attribute completely and do it in JS. You can't really have both.

Comment: @ErcanPeker yes I have added.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan how can I make changes to the `src` from server side without having `runat` attribute? If there is a way then I will remove the `runat` attribute completely and change the `src`

Comment: @ErcanPeker I realized that I had missed it. I have edited the post now.

Comment: How you would code this depends on where `condition` comes from and what it is.  If it's a choice the user has made on the currently displayed web page, it'd be better off to change the .src using Javascript.  If it's only a server-side condition, then you could put an if in your aspx page that checks that condition and displays the appropriate image.

Answer (score 0):

Check the "UniqueID" generated for the image. ASP.NET is changing the ID for elements runat=server to something like "ctl00_imgseats". Depending on the depth of the DOM it can be a very long ID.

Or change the jQuery selector to the class: $('img.HeaderGradient') for example. You can also use a dummy css class.

Answer (score 0):

for access any control of runnat="server" in jquery you need to access them by their unique ID i.e. $('#<%=imgseats.ClickID%>') instead of $("#imgseats").

$(document).ready(function () {
    //doing something

```
$('#<%=imgseats.ClientID%>').click(function () {
// doing something
});
```

});